# SAS proc means together with creating variable

Tags: variables, sas, mean

I want to do proc means on variable, which I should create in my dataset based on some other existing variables. Can I manage to do this in one procedure?

My hopeless trial was

```
data example;
do i =1 to 100;
   x=i**2;
   output;
end;
run;

proc means data = example mean;
var y = x + i;
run;
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `PROC SQL` procedure which covers most of the summary stats producible using `PROC MEANS`

```
proc sql;
select mean(x+1) as y
from example;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `VIEW` and do the means on that.

```
data example_v/view=example_v;
set example;
y=x+i;
run;

proc means data=example_v mean;
var y;
run;
```

VIEW is like a dataset, except that it isn't really run until it's needed - so even if `example` is very large it will take no time to create the view, and then approximately the same time to run the `proc means` as it would otherwise have with `example`.